# Shortcut for turning on/off speakers

Tags: audio, shortcuts, headset

I have USB headset and in order to use my speakers i have to turn off headset from sound menu.
I have made shortcut to this menu already but having shortcut directly for it would be perfect.

Comment: You might want to mention your OS?

Comment: Also, please include what you've tried already, where you're getting stuck, and maybe an actual question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use Autohotkey scripting, there is a library called Vista sound, which works with everything after and including Vista.